# How to process large volumes of records with callouts?

Tags: batch, callout, governorlimits

My client needs to import PDFs from Dropbox, match them to an invoice (where filename without suffix = field reference on invoice object), and attach to the appropriate invoice, then move the Dropbox file from its current location to an Archive folder.  At an estimate (because Dropbox doesn't have simple "how many files in this folder" API), there are at least than 300,000 files.  Could be quite a lot more than that, no easy way to tell.

The lifecycle is

- Call Dropbox to get list of filenames. This list is throttled by their API
- If the response field `hasMore` = true, get the response field `cursor`
- Call the Dropbox API again with the cursor to get the next set of filenames
- Repeat until `hasMore` is false
- Iterate through the list of filenames, requesting the file content
- Look for a matching invoice, if found, attach the PDF
- Repeat until all attached where possible
- Iterate the "successful" files
- Call the Dropbox API to move them to the Archived folder

I've approached this with a Scheduled job that fires a batch job to carry out this process, but things are unravelling.  I've had to scale the batch size down to 100, because of the number of callouts governor limit.  This has resulted in hitting the too many AsyncExecutions governor limit.

At this point, I'm running out of options.  Not sure whether Platform Events would add anything other than additional layers of complexity here.

What other techniques are available to me?

Comment: Is this a one-time job?

Comment: It's an ongoing job, but not (hopefully!) in anywhere near those kind of volumes - that size issue is for scooping up the backlog

Comment: /2/files/search_v2 sounds applicable to your use case. This could avoid the "search the entire folder per record" scenario, no?

Comment: @sfdcfox - if it was "given a Salesforce trigger, go find the corresponding PDF" (where trigger in the generic sense of a triggering change of state), then yes, but this is a third party system dropping invoice PDFs in the folder and Salesforce having to periodically poll for new invoices that may have arrived, with no idea which ones

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now. Given you expect that the folder will be manageable after the initial sync, I'd do that part from a UI, giving you the ability to hold these hundreds of thousands of files in memory for easier processing. Apex really doesn't handle what you're trying to do very well.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "from a UI" - can you elaborate please?

Comment: I'd build a LWC/Visualforce/Aura thing to query the hundreds of thousands of files, then match them up to database records. Having "unlimited" memory and callouts is much easier to work with.

Comment: Process backlog offline (bulk export from Dropbox, bulk import into SF). Subsequent changes on Dropbox side should fly into Salesforce via Dropbox webhhooks:  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, this is an ETL job, which you are trying to replicate. You can consider the following approaches:

1. ETL
   Maybe be difficult to sell, but there are a lot of tools available on market including SaaS tools or free as Talend.
2. Build solution on the Force.com platform
   My understanding is that the volumes will be problematic only for initial migration activity and should be much smaller later on. In that case, consider doing migration over a few days to avoid hitting the limit with batch apex. You will need to create an additional layer to manage job state, such as used resources, place of the cursor, etc.
3. Build solution using salesforce cli
   You can build the solution on top of https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility . You would need skills around building cli plugins like nodejs etc.

Please chose solution based on the resources and skills available.